# Javascript number comparison not correct

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some maths in javascript but I'm not getting the expected result all the time.

Here's my function - some parts have been simplified.

```
function updateExample($widget) {
    var loan = parseInt($widget.attr("data-loan"), 10);
    var term = parseInt($widget.attr("data-term"), 10);

    // Get the best rate
    var rateInfo = GetRateInfo(loan, term);
    var annualRate = rateInfo[2];

    // Calculate costs
    var rate = (term === 1
        ? annualRate / 365 * 30
        : annualRate / 12) / 100;

    var pow = Math.pow(rate + 1, term);
    var payment = round(rate * pow / (pow - 1) * loan, 2);
    var totalRepayable = round(payment * term, 2);
    var totalCostCap = round(loan * 2, 2);
    var costCapped = false;
    console.log(totalRepayable);
    console.log(totalCostCap);

    if (totalRepayable > totalCostCap) {
        console.log("capped");
    }
}
```

One of the tests that's failing is when I pass in a loan of 500 and a term of 1.

As you can see, I log 3 values to the console. The first 2 values output are:

620.00 and 1000.00

Given the values, I expect the following test to fail but it doesn't.

if (totalRepayable > totalCostCap)
if (620.00 > 1000.00)

The console log reads "capped" to prove the if statement has been entered.

I'm not a javascript expert by any means but I can't see how this is failing.

Here's the custom round function:

```
function round(value, decimals) {
    return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals).toFixed(decimals);
}
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What's your `round` function?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise that was a custom function - let me see.

Comment: round function seems like returning a string?

Comment: Added the custom round function to the code above.

Comment: Incomplete code...

GetRateInfo function details missing

Comment: @deedub `typeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: @JaredSmith Correct. Your point?

Comment: That you wrote it like a function call, which could confuse someone new to JS (like the OP). The parens are completely unnecessary. The only reason it even works at all the way you wrote it is that parens have a higher operator precedence than `typeof` (otherwise you'd get a ReferenceError). What you wrote is evaluated like this `typeof (totalRepayable)` and like any other single expression `totalRepayable` is going to evaluate to itself.

Comment: Alright. Removing to avoid confusion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show your `round` function, but I'm assuming it's using `.toFixed()`. The problem is you don't actually *have* arbitrary precision floating point numbers, so it converts to string, and

```
console.log("620.00" > "1000.00"); // true
```

The thing that tipped me off is that if you log a number like `620.00` to the console it automatically truncates it, the fact that you were seeing trailing zeros suggests it's a string.

### Update

Yeah, now that you posted that it's definitely returning a string. The last part of the return value is a call to `.toFixed()`. Just cast the result back to a number to do the comparison.

Comment: I've found and added the round function - you're correct in assuming it uses .toFixed()

Comment: @JohnOhara yup. Just cast the results back to numbers to do the comparison `(+totalRepayable > +totalCostCap)`. Not sure why Brendan Eich thought greater-than comparisons on strings using unicode point values was a good idea, but eh.

Comment: @JaredSmith WOAH! Do you have any documentation describing how that works? I've never seen that technique before

Comment: @TheCrzyMan you mean the unary plus operator? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus

Comment: Thanks for the help Jared. I've removed the rounding on totalCostCap altogether and moved the other 2 rounds after the if statement when the numbers are finalised, no no need to stringify then cast back.

Comment: @JohnOhara glad your problem is solved, you're welcome.

Comment: @TheCrzyMan you're welcome. That was actually a little harder to find than I thought it would be :)